# where can I find a right side dropbar hydraulic brake only lever? I'm using bar end shifters

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I am using a 10 speed bar end shifter on drop bar. I have hydraulic brakes and can not find any non shift right side brake levers. Only left side. Any suggestions on how I can rework a left side hydraulic brake only lever to work on the right side?

Comment: i use a set of sram hydraulic apex1 levers with the shifter paddle removed. it's a decent option, easy to find used too.

Answer (score 2):

The left-side hydraulic-brake-only shifter is for a 1x setup.  I have not found a single-speed hydraulic brake groupset for drop bars after searching.

- ST-RS685 is a Shimano 105 11 speed groupset that has hydraulic braking and mechanical shifting.  You might simply not connect the shifting cables.  Many of the higher-end hydraulic groupsets are for Electric shifting.
- Shimano's GRX groupset might suit your needs too, but again you'd have to leave the shifter cables disconnected from the levers.  If you go this route, it would be worth plugging the shifter cable holes using a blob of hot melt glue or similar.  And the levers will still be able to click if you push them sideways which may be confusing/annoying.
- TRP has hydraulic-only levers with no shifting called the [RRL-Alloy](https://trpcycling.com/product/rrl-alloy/)  but I can't see if it suits the right-hand side of the bike or is left-side only.
  UPDATE  "Sold as a set (left and right)"
- Magura had HS77, a hydraulic only drop bar lever in the `90s  complete with purple anodised levers which were for use with HS66 rim brakes.  I don't know if these would work with modern disk brakes, but they would likely use Magura's "Royal Blood" fluid.   
  https://www.cxmagazine.com/tbt-magura-hydraulic-cantilever-brake-drop-bar-lever-hs66-hs77-rim

LINKS: https://www.mtbr.com/threads/drop-bar-hydraulic-brake-levers-without-shifters.1065901/

Good luck with your search !